# WS_FTP Pro: How to transfer multiple files at the same time?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, compression

1. I have WS_FTP Pro 12.6, and I am wondering how can I transfer more than one file at the same time? (upload or download).  The `Options > Transfers` has only options of "Maximum number of concurrent transfers", and I set it to 20 but still it uploads or downloads 1 file at a time from any server.

   That is so slow for small files, which should take seconds to upload, but they take many minutes depending on the number of files.
2. There is an option of "Compression mode", but after uploading, where is the option to "decompress" the compressed files in WS_FTP Pro?

Answer (score 1):

I use both WS_FTP and WinSCP for filebrowsing/ftp transfers respectively. I find WinSCP to be vastly faster, keeping network, traffic, resources, etc. all constant. There's clearly something on the software side accounting for the difference, but I don't know what.

Others have asked this question before, and IPSwitch seems to disown that they have anything to do with the problem: https://community.ipswitch.com/s/article/Slow-transfers-1307565962822